# Unable to understand how State Monad get it's state in this code

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

I kind of understand State Monad's usefulness it propagating new values in a sequential execution. But in the following code, I'm having trouble in understanding how and where `addResult` get it's updated state everytime it gets evaluated.

```
fizzBuzz :: Integer -> String
fizzBuzz n
   | n `mod` 15 == 0 = "FizzBuzz"
   | n `mod` 5 == 0 = "Buzz"
   | n `mod` 3 == 0 = "Fizz"
   | otherwise = show n

fizzbuzzList :: [Integer] -> [String]
fizzbuzzList list = execState (mapM_ addResult list) []

addResult :: Integer -> State [String] ()
addResult n = do
    xs <- get
    let result = fizzBuzz n
    put (result : xs)

main :: IO ()
main = mapM_ putStrLn $ fizzbuzzList [1..100]
```

This code evaluates to produce

> 1, 2, Fizz...

I just couldn't figure out how the new value produced by `addResult` gets appended to the previously produced list. Can you please help me understand how `mapM_ addResult list` does it's stuff here?

Comment: The state is being threaded through the State monad. `addResult` is doing a `get` to retrieve the list so far, and then it uses `put` to put a new list into the state monad.  The initial state is the [] that is being fed to `execState`

Comment: As a complete tangent: this code triggers a very strong "ICK" reaction for me. `fizzbuzzList = map fizzBuzz . reverse` would be much more idiomatic. It's also much more obvious how to change the code in case you didn't want the answers backwards after all.

Comment: @DanielWagner This code is from the book Haskell Programming from First Priniciples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have correctly observed, the State monad is used to thread some external 'state' value through a series of computations. However, you ask how this state is 'persisted' across multiple invocations of your function `addResult :: Integer -> State [String] ()` on each value of the list `list`. The trick is the definition of `mapM_`. We'll start by considering the simpler function `mapM`:

```
mapM f [] = return []
mapM f (x:xs) = do
    fx <- f x
    fxs <- mapM f xs
    return (fx : fxs)
```

If we mentally 'expand' this recursive definition out with, say, an example list `[x1,x2,x3,x4,...,xn]`, we'll observe that the value of `mapM f [x1,...,xn]` would be another monadic computation:

```
do
    fx1 <- f x1
    fx2 <- f x2
    -- etc.
    fxn <- f xn
    return [fx1,fx2,...,fxn]
```

So `mapM` basically 'sticks together' a bunch of monadic computations into one big one, by running them together in order. Which explains how you build up a list instead of producing many smaller ones: the `get` at the beginning of `addResult` gets the state *from the last run*, not from the beginning, because you're running all the computations together, like so:

```
do
    fl0 <- addResult (list !! 0)
    fl1 <- addResult (list !! 1)
    -- etc. like before
```

(If you read carefully, you'll notice I've been talking about `mapM`, but you actually used `mapM_`. They're exactly the same, except that the latter returns `()`.)

Comment: In what sense is `mapM` "simpler" than `mapM_`? Yes, there are more laws available to reason about it (none of which you've used), but the actual function is actually a tad more complicated.

Comment: @dfeuer True. I suppose I was using "simpler" to mean "more foundational"; that is, you can get `mapM_` from `mapM` but not the other way around.

Comment: Totally forgot the definition of mapM. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 2):

`State` can be thought of as being defined like

```
data State s a = s -> (a, s)
```

which means that

```
Integer -> State [String] ()
```

is equivalent to

```
Integer -> [String] -> ((), [String])
```

So `addResult` takes an integer and returns a *function* that takes a state and returns a tuple containing the new state.

`mapM_`, roughly speaking, chains a group of these functions together. Using regular map would produce a list of `State` functions, each expecting a state and returning a new state. `mapM_` takes the further step of binding each `State` to the previous. The end result is not a list of `State` values, but a single `State` value that forms a pipeline.

`execState` then provides the initial state in one end of the pipeline, and returns the final state from the other end.